# Importing Twitter Bootstrap Template in Weebly

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter, import

I have an account with weebly and I just purchased a bootstrap template 2 days ago.
This is the link https://wrapbootstrap.com/theme/clean-canvas-business-theme-WB02634G3

I'm trying to import that template to weebly but it doesn't seem to work properly.
Can anybody guide me to do it?
or maybe tell me what should I include on the css.

I know a bit of coding but I'm a compete beginner at this.
Appreciate the help and if by any chance someone can do it for me i would gladly pay for it.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this tech note from other templates maker?

http://divtagtutorials.com/install-template/

(how-to on installation of custom template in Weebly)

Peter